# How do I clean up after deleting an L7 ingress in Google Container Engine/Kubernetes v1.4.5?

Tags: google-compute-engine, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I've deleted an L7 ingress in Google Container Engine (Kubernetes v1.4.5) via the following command: `kubectl delete -f l7-ingress.yaml`. However, resources still linger, including its backend services so that I cannot recreate the ingress because my quota for backend services (3) is reached. Even after deleting the GKE cluster in question, the backend services and instance groups linger.

If I try to delete one of the backend services via `gcloud` the following happens:

```
$ gcloud compute backend-services delete k8s-be-31917--0901b0d0f6edfe9d
The following backend services will be deleted:
 - [k8s-be-31917--0901b0d0f6edfe9d]

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.backend-services.delete) Some requests did not succeed:
 - The backend_service resource 'k8s-be-31917--0901b0d0f6edfe9d' is already being used by 'k8s-um-default-l7-ingress--0901b0d0f6edfe9d'
```

Moreover, if I try to delete one of the instance groups created by the ingress from the Google Cloud Console, an "undefined" error is reported in a dialog.

How do I remove all resources associated with an L7 ingress in Google Container Engine??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this changed from few months ago, when I was using GCE, but I remember it was not allowed to delete the L7 LB. Instead you can scale it to 0.

```
kubectl scale rc l7-lb-controller --replicas=0 --namespace=kube-system
```

Comment: I'm not so sure there is any L7 controller to scale down, as I've even deleted the cluster?

Comment: Ouch, just saw. You go to Networking, Load balancing and click "advanced menu". There you'll have "BackendServices". you can try delete it from there.

Comment: I couldn't see any "advanced menu", but I did find load balancers from Networking. After deleting the L7 load balancer, the backend services disappeared and I could also remove the instance group. Thanks!